# Are ruby 2.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0p645 different?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, napa

I'm trying to follow this [article](https://github.com/bellycard/napa/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md), and when I do a bundle install, it says

```
rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed
```

So I try ruby -v and it shows

```
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [i686-linux]
```

Is ruby 2.0.0 different than what I have in my Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I believe they *are* different releases, though when looking at the list of installable versions within rbenv 2.0.0 all by itself is not one of them.

To answer your question, yes, they are probably different versions, but your problem probably lies within the Gemfile or Gemfile.lock included within the results of the `napa new` when it is run.  In there, it's likely there is a hard-coded setting to use ruby version 2.0.0 which would not match the requirements when comparing against what is on your system.